# Show images in a slider using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm making a simple jquery slider. My code is given below. Please tell me how to 
show the images of some id that I have inserted in a div of class slider. my jquery code is not working.

**the css code:**

```
.slider {
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-image: url(img/loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.shadow {
    background-image: url(img/shadow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: -55px auto;
}

.slider img {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;

}
```

**the jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider #1').fadeIn(2000);   
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="slider"> 
    <img id="1" src="img/1.jpg" border="0" alt="Intro" /> 
    <img id="2" src="img/2.jpg" border="0" alt="Course" /> 
    <img id="3" src="img/3.jpg" border="0" alt="My Slider" /> 
</div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Could you, besides explaining better the problem, post also the HTML?

Comment: <div class="slider">
<img  id="1" src="img/1.jpg" border="0" alt="Intro" />
<img  id="2" src="img/2.jpg" border="0" alt="Course" />
<img  id="3" src="img/3.jpg" border="0" alt="My Slider" />
</div>
<div class="shadow"></div>

Comment: i set the images display to none and tried to show the image of id 1 that i've put it in a div of class slider with jquery but it's now showing.

Comment: are you using html5?  if not your id won't be valid which could be causing this not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Slider FIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/32Eje/)

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.slider :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.slider');
    },
    3000);
});
```

Comment: This is fade effect. how to do the bounce effect in the slider?

Comment: @ZAynALi for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/32Eje/3/ If you use this don't forget to include jquery easing plugin http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ Change the speed of the slideUp() and slideDown() to your needs..

Comment: Thanks alot Sbml :) this is very easy to use